# Rails redirect to .json file instead the created item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails app I need to add a new item into catalog over JSON, but after POST it's redirect me to .json file instead the created item's page. My `create` function is:

```
  def create
    @item = Item.new(items_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.save
        format.html{redirect_to @item, success: 'Item was created'}
        format.js {}
        format.json{render :json => @item}
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.js {}
        format.json { render json: @item.errors.full_messages, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

My form for new item:

```
      <%= form_for @item, remote: true, format: :json, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|%>
      <%= f.label :name, 'Item name:' %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, :class=>'input-block-level' %>

      <%= f.label :type_id, 'Cathegory:' %>
      <%= collection_select(:item, :type_id, Type.all, :id, :name, {}, {:class=>'input-block-level'}) %>

      <%= f.label :description, 'Description' %>
      <%= f.text_area :description, :class=>'input-block-level' %>

      <%= f.label :price, 'Price' %>
      <%= f.text_field :price %>

      <p>
        <label>Photo</label>
        <%= f.file_field :image, :class=>'input-block-level' %>
      </p>

      <%= f.submit 'Add item', class: 'btn btn-success btn-block btn-large' %>
  <% end %>
```

JSON file in browser after post:

```
{"id":80,"type_id":7,"image":{"url":"/uploads/item/image/80/3572746998.png"},"description":"Sample description","created_at":"2014-06-20T10:02:01.574Z","updated_at":"2014-06-20T10:02:01.574Z","name":"Test","price":100}
```

What can I do to fix this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to create a new item and on successful creation do you want to show the item that is created? The question is not clear actually.

Comment: Yes. But i see only raw .json

Comment: You can remove the format: :json as mentioned in the answer by jbmyid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove format: :json from `form_for` helper method.

```
<%= form_for @item, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|%>
      ....
<% end %>
```